# Limit the size of FlatList to not force the footer to go offscreen

Tags: react-native, responsive-design, react-native-flatlist

Is there a way to limit the size of FlatList in such a way that the bottom View with the green background would always be visible, no matter the amount of items in the list?

Here is the code:

```
const FlatListTest = () => {
    const data = []
    for (let i = 0 ; i < 30; i++) {
        data.push(i)
    }

    return <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 40}} />
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={item => (
                <Text>
                    {item.item}
                </Text>
            )} 
            />
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: 40}} />
    </View>
}
```

In responsive design mode it renders to this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkO4f.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish that is to use absolute position for the footer and set the bottom margin for the list to be equal in height of the footer. Something like this:

```js
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 40 }} />
  <FlatList
    style={{ marginBottom: 40 }}
...
  />
  <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      width: '100%',
      height: 40,
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
    }}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: What if the size of the bottom View isn't known?

Comment: Just tested out the code, nothing has changed for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping your Flatlist with parent View with height you can accomplish that
Here is an example code (I have given 300 height update this height with your desired height):

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 40}} />
    <View style={{
        height:300, //update with desired height
    }}>
        <FlatList 
            data={data}
            renderItem={item=> (
                <Text>{item.item}</Text>
                )}
            />
    </View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: 40}} />
</View>
```

Feel Free to ask any questions.

Comment: What if the size of the bottom View isn't known?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Adding the `height: 0` style to the ScrollView (for some reason) fixes the issue.